# Why are my making predictions so slow using Faster RCNN using Tensorflows Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Tensorflows Object Detection api to train my own object detection with my own data set. My issue is that it takes roughly 25-30sec to predict each image. That includes reading the image and drawing the bounding boxes. I am running on a NVIDIA K80 GPU with 1 core. Any guidance to make this go faster? I basically adopted the prediction script from the Object Detection api.

Here are the two functions I used to make my predictions:

```
def predict_image(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS, PATH_TO_CKPT, category_index, save_path):
    detection_graph = load_detection_graph(PATH_TO_CKPT)
    prediction_dict = defaultdict()
    start_time = time.time()
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
        toc = time.time()
        filename = image_path.split('/')[-1]
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
        # result image with boxes and labels on it.
        image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Actual detection.
        output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph, filename)
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.

        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          output_dict['detection_boxes'],
          output_dict['detection_classes'],
          output_dict['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
        prediction_dict[filename] = output_dict

        tic = time.time()
        print('{0} saved in {1:.2f}sec'.format(filename, tic-toc))
    end_time = time.time()



def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph, filename):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['filename'] = filename
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict
```

Comment: You should time each operation to find the bottleneck. I'm thinking its the opening image part.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @dsBoulder I am also facing the issue, the prediction is taking around 25-30 secs on GPU. Did you find any solution?. If yes can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I read same thing on a github page, seems to be problem with Image.open I/O operation, this time can be significantly reduces by using opencv. Using tf server, I am able to achieve inference in 0.16 sec using this GPU.

Answer (score -1):

If you are making multiple prediction on same model then you can reduce the prediction time by loading the detection graph once and only run the session for each prediction. This will take time for first prediction but succeeding prediction will take less time.
But in case of using different model for each prediction, Ididn't find any way out.